# How do I refer to variable in func argument when same is used in foreach

Tags: rebol

How can I refer to date as argument in f within the foreach loop if date is also used as block element var ? Am I obliged to rename my date var ?

```
f: func[data [block!] date [date!]][
    foreach [date o h l c v] data [

    ]
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A: simple, compose is your best friend.

```
f: func[data [block!] date [date!]][
    foreach [date str] data compose [
        print (date)
        print date
    ]
]

>> f [2010-09-01 "first of sept" 2010-10-01 "first of october"] now

7-Sep-2010/21:19:05-4:00
1-Sep-2010
7-Sep-2010/21:19:05-4:00
1-Oct-2010
```

Comment: obviously, all parens are replaced, so in some situations the above is either impossible or unwieldy, but in the vast majority of cases, it works.

Comment: Ah, this is a clever answer!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to either change the parameter name from date or assign it to a local variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the date argument inside the foreach loop by binding the 'date word from the function specification to the data argument:

```
>> f: func[data [block!] date [date!]][
[    foreach [date o h l c v] data [     
[        print last reduce bind find first :f 'date 'data
[        print date
[        ]
[    ]

>> f [1-1-10 1 2 3 4 5 2-1-10  1 2 3 4 5] 8-9-10
8-Sep-2010
1-Jan-2010
8-Sep-2010
2-Jan-2010
```

It makes the code very difficult to read though. I think it would be better to assign the date argument to a local variable inside the function as Graham suggested.

```
>> f: func [data [block!] date [date!] /local the-date ][
[    the-date: :date                                       
[    foreach [date o h l c v] data [                       
[        print the-date                                        
[        print date                                            
[        ]
[    ]
>> f [1-1-10 1 2 3 4 5 2-1-10  1 2 3 4 5] 8-9-10         
8-Sep-2010
1-Jan-2010
8-Sep-2010
2-Jan-2010
```

Comment: The technique of binding an additional argument to a block would be more difficult to apply if the foreach loop was iterating over the elements of the block one at a time. There would probably be an additional iteration for the date.